# Check if numbers are in a specific sequence

Tags: java, arrays, int, modulo

I have an int array with 4 numbers that are sorted ascendingly.

I want to find out whether these numbers match this rule:

```
1, 2, 3, 4 or
5, 6, 7, 8 or
9, 10, 11, 12 or
13, 14, 15, 16
etc.
```

They cannot be

```
2, 3, 4, 5 or
4, 5, 6, 7 or
23, 24, 25, 26
etc
```

So they must be in a sequence but only in these 4-groups!

**I tried** to add all numbers (for example 1+2+3+4) and do the sum modulo 12 and the result is always 10, 2, 6, 10, 2, 6, etc. My idea was to check if the result is one of these three numbers 2, 6, or 10.

**But it can't work** because for example (17+18+19+20)%12 is 2 which is legit but for example (2+3+4+5)%12 is 2 too but it's not legitimate so it'd be a wrong result.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a 2-Dimensional array. For each row, find if the value of column y is 4 + the value of the previous column, x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let the numbers be

```
a, a+1, a+2, a+3
```

The rule is

```
a % 4 == 1    // is the same as:  a & 3 == 1
```

Comment: +1 for bitwise and. Also (a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 - 10) % 4 = 0 he grinned and said.

Comment: Sorry I';m new this is my first post but I accepted the answer now

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question clearly, then you just need to check whether your last number in the sequence is divisible by 4 or not. If it is divisible by 4, it is a valid sequence.

So, if your sequence is: - `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `a4`. Check this condition: -

```
a4 % 4 == 0
```

If the above condition is true, then you have a valid sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Say The first number of your array is `x`
Then `x` modulo `4` must be equal to `1`

```
if (a[0]%4 == 1)
  return true;
else 
  return false;
```

Or alternatively if
`a[1] % 4 == 2`

or

`a[2] % 4 == 3`

or

```
a[3] % 4 == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest rule I can see is that;

```
array[3] % 4 == 0
```

That is, the final element in the array evenly divides by 4. That will be a simple solution.